# Keras NoteBook GPU Timeout

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, keras

I am trying to run keras with tensorflow on a windows 10 machine with my GTX 980 gpu on a jupyter notebook. If I run tensorflow alone with my gpu, its works perfectly fine without any issues. But problems arise with the keras interface for high number of epochs.

The keras model uses the GPU and gives an output if my number of epochs is low like the following

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy', ['accuracy'])
    history = model.fit(X_normalized,y_one_hot,batch_size=128,nb_epoch=2,validation_split=0.2)
```

Following is the output

> Train on 31367 samples, validate on 7842 samples
>   Epoch 1/2
>   31367/31367 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 1.7640 - acc: 0.5438 - val_loss: 1.2872 - val_acc: 0.6486 - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.8827 - acc: 0.5145 - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.7732 - acc: 0.5416
>
> Epoch 2/2
>   31367/31367 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.8539 - acc: 0.7765 - val_loss: 0.7958 - val_acc: 0.7615

If the number of epochs is high then it will timeout with the following error and the webpage says busy

> WebSocket ping timeout after 119999 ms.

How do i fix this error?

Comment: You should provide the complete error message.

Comment: I think it's a known issue with Jupyter. You can download your notebook as `.py` file and run it from terminal

Answer (score 0):

I guess this issue is related to TDR(Timeout Detection and Recovery) on Windows. 
Basically, the OS thought the GPU hang and do not response any more, so OS will reboot the graphics card. You can try to disable the TDR or extend the up limit of TdRDelay. More details can be found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/tdr-registry-keys.